# Ruby on Rails default to POST when accessed with Android Studio

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, android-studio

I have some experience using android studio but am fairly new to ruby on rails and have been trying to create a restful application. I generated a scaffold called Employer so it has the default routes,

```
employers GET    /employers(.:format)    employers#index
          POST   /employers(.:format)    employers#create
```

and have been trying to read the employers list by parsing the JSON like so in android studio:

```
ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    URL url = null;
    String response = "";
    TextView errdisplay = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.fishytext);

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        //this method will be running on UI thread
        pdLoading.setMessage("\tLoading...");
        pdLoading.setCancelable(false);
        pdLoading.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {

            // Enter URL address where your json file resides
            url = new URL("MYIP.../employers.json");


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.toString();
        }
        try {

            // Setup HttpURLConnection class to send and receive data from php and mysql
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

            // setDoOutput to true as we recieve data from json file
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return e1.toString();
        }

        try {

            int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();

            // Check if successful connection made
            if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {


                // Read data sent from server
                InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                String line;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line);
                    response+= line;
                }
                return (result.toString());

            } else {
                return ("unsuccessful");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.toString();
        } finally {
            conn.disconnect();
        }
    }
```

My problem is that despite changing my RequestMethod to GET it defaults to POST in rails which has left me quite confused.

```
Started POST "/employers.json"
```

I understand this is a routes issue and have managed to get it work(if you can call it that) through forcibly changing the routes as shown below but i realize this will affect my future attempts at REST.

```
post 'employers' => 'employers#index'
```

I apologize if this isn't the right format but i would be very grateful for any advice on how to fix my routes or how to access the JSON url. Thank you for your time.

Comment: The request is coming as POST from Android Studio. Can you confirm the request type made from Java code is POST/GET?

Comment: I can confirm that the request method is GET, even if i didn't set it in the above code GET seems to be the default in android studio. Thank you.

Comment: Can you post how is the route specified in  routes.rb for employers? For testing if the request is coming as get or not. Just have `get "/employers", to: "employers#index"`. The previous line will make sure that there is no POST route defined and if you are still getting a POST it would mean you have to change code in studio.

Comment: The request seems to still be coming in as POST. Here are my routes `employers GET    /employers(.:format)                                 employers#index
                               POST   /employers(.:format)                                 employers#create
                  new_employer GET    /employers/new(.:format)                             employers#new
                 edit_employer GET    /employers/:id/edit(.:format)                        employers#edit
                      employer GET    /employers/:id(.:format)                             employers#show
 `

Comment: Rails cannot change the request type of an incoming request. It just matches the incoming request with the defined routes. So here the request is coming as POST. To check if Rails understands get "/employers", to: "employers/index", can you also install postman extension in chrome or firefox and try to make a get request lile this: `localhost:3000/employers.json` with request type as GET. If this is working then Rails routing is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to the user sahil for pointing me in the right direction. At the moment i still haven't managed to access Rails though anything other than POST so for anybody in a similar situation the work around im using is to change the routes to modify the url.

```
post 'employers/display' => 'employers#index'
post 'employers/newindex' => 'employers#create'
```

so that the url i need to access instead will be "/employers/display.json" for GET and "/employers/newindex.json" for POST, from how i defined them in the employers_controller. It's not a very good answer but ill update this again when i know more.